Calculation Ema TRadingView & Ninjatrader different
on this page: https://www.tradingcode.net/tradingview/exponential-moving-average/ there is the formula for calculating ema in trading view:
pine_ema(src, length) =>
 alpha = 2 / (length + 1)
 sum = 0.0
 sum := na(sum[1]) ?
 src:
 alpha * src + (1 - alpha) * nz(sum[1])

I adapted it for NT8:
private double CustomEMA(int length)
 {
 double alpha = 2.0 / (length + 1.0);

 if (isFirstCalculation)
 {
 double sum = 0.0;
 for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
 {
 sum += Open[i];
 }

 lastEma = sum / length;
 isFirstCalculation = false;
}
else
{
lastEma = alpha * Open[0] + (1 - alpha) * lastEma;
}

return lastEma;
}

with private double lastEma = 0.0; and private bool isFirstCalculation = true; declared as variables global.
I think my code is correct.
However the results are different:

TW : 20409.74 NT8 : 20410.55


TW : 20356.14 NT8 : 20356.79


TW : 20310.51 NT8 : 20311.03


TW : 20321.41 NT8 : 20321.83


TW : 20441.98 NT8 : 20442.31

What do I I missed???
I would simply like to code in NT8 a custom ema that exactly reproduces the behavior of the tradingview ema
Thank you for your help
//------------------------------------
Comparing the Tradingview and NT8 logs allowed me to see that the open data are the same but there is a "weirdness" in TRdaingView :
TradingView :
2024-10-15T00:00:00.000+02:00 ;Open : 20637.5 ;EMA(9) : 20345.0939209805
2024-10-16T00:00:00.000+02:00 ;Open : 20340 ;EMA(9) : 20344.0751367844
2024-10-17T00:00:00.000+02:00 ;Open : 20332 ;EMA(9) : 20341.6601094275
2024-10-18T00:00:00.000+02:00 ;Open : 20385.5 ;EMA(9) : 20350.428087542
2024-10-21T00:00:00.000+02:00 ;Open : 20495.75 ;EMA(9) : 20379.4924700336
2024-10-22T00:00:00.000+02:00 ;Open : 20518.25 ;EMA(9) : 20407.2439760269
2024-10-23T00:00:00.000+02:00 ;Open : 20522.75 ;EMA(9) : 20430.3451808215
2024-10-24T00:00:00.000+02:00 ;Open : 20299.5 ;EMA(9) : 20404.1761446572
2024-10-25T00:00:00.000+02:00 ;Open : 20385 ;EMA(9) : 20400.3409157258
2024-10-27T23:00:00.000+01:00 ;Open : 20524 ;EMA(9) : 20425.0727325806
2024-10-28T23:00:00.000+01:00 ;Open : 20508 ;EMA(9) : 20441.6581860645  NOT ON CHART
2024-10-29T23:00:00.000+01:00 ;Open : 20725 ;EMA(9) : 20498.3265488516
2024-10-30T23:00:00.000+01:00 ;Open : 20486 ;EMA(9) : 20495.8612390813
2024-10-31T23:00:00.000+01:00 ;Open : 20065.25 ;EMA(9) : 20409.738991265
2024-11-01 NOT IN LOG BUT ON CHART
2024-11-04T00:00:00.000+01:00 ;Open : 20141.75 ;EMA(9) : 20356.141193012
2024-11-05T00:00:00.000+01:00 ;Open : 20128 ;EMA(9) : 20310.5129544096
2024-11-06T00:00:00.000+01:00 ;Open : 20365 ;EMA(9) : 20321.4103635277
2024-11-07T00:00:00.000+01:00 ;Open : 20924.25 ;EMA(9) : 20441.9782908222
2024-11-08T00:00:00.000+01:00 ;Open : 21225 ;EMA(9) : 20598.5826326577

NinjaTrader 8 :
2024-10-15 23:00:00;OPen : 20637.5;EMA(9) : 20343.5763065492
2024-10-16 23:00:00;OPen : 20340;EMA(9) : 20344.7610452393
2024-10-17 23:00:00;OPen : 20332;EMA(9) : 20349.4088361915
2024-10-18 23:00:00;OPen : 20385.5;EMA(9) : 20376.2270689532
2024-10-21 23:00:00;OPen : 20495.75;EMA(9) : 20404.8816551625
2024-10-22 23:00:00;OPen : 20539;EMA(9) : 20432.30532413
2024-10-23 23:00:00;OPen : 20522.75;EMA(9) : 20389.944259304
2024-10-24 23:00:00;OPen : 20299.5;EMA(9) : 20388.0054074432
2024-10-25 23:00:00;OPen : 20385;EMA(9) : 20410.1543259546
2024-10-28 22:00:00;OPen : 20524;EMA(9) : 20427.5234607637
2024-10-29 22:00:00;OPen : 20508;EMA(9) : 20481.3187686109
2024-10-30 22:00:00;OPen : 20725;EMA(9) : 20492.0050148887
2024-10-31 22:00:00;OPen : 20486;EMA(9) : 20397.954011911
2024-11-01 22:00:00;OPen : 20065.25;EMA(9) : 20349.0132095288
2024-11-04 23:00:00;OPen : 20141.75;EMA(9) : 20296.410567623
2024-11-05 23:00:00;OPen : 20128;EMA(9) : 20305.4784540984
2024-11-06 23:00:00;OPen : 20365;EMA(9) : 20423.1827632787
2024-11-07 23:00:00;OPen : 20924.25;EMA(9) : 20583.496210623


Did you try to debug and see where the mismatch is coming from?

In tradingview i can't see calculation steps but in NT8 The calculation have no error and the bars data are corrects so i think it's a logical problem in the adaptation. i think i missed something but what ???

Zou can use log.*() functions on Tradingview to debug your code.

Thank you but i can't see the calculation process, only if there is an error, or any info i ask but not the logical, only the result.
